# Dynamically adding tabs to JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

In my main I loop over each `League` as below:

```
for (League l : t.getLeagues()) {
    LeaguePanel leaguePanel = new LeaguePanel(l);
    roundTabs.addTab(l.getName(), leaguePanel);
}
```

This should then create a `JPanel` and add it to the tab.

```
public class LeaguePanel extends JPanel {

    private League league;
    private JComboBox roundComboBox;

    LeaguePanel(League l) {
        league = l;
        JPanel leagePanel = new JPanel();
        leagePanel.add(new JLabel("Tournament Information"));
    }
```

However, the tab gets created but nothing appears within it

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add things to your `LeaguePanel` object, not to a new `JPanel` :

```
JPanel leagePanel = new JPanel();
leagePanel.add(new JLabel("Tournament Information"));
```

becomes

```
this.add(new JLabel("Tournament Information"));
```

Because it's your `LeaguePanel` that you add to the tabbed pane .

Comment: Jeez. I wish i had another pair of eyes here!~
Thanks. Solved!